# Why does conda not upgrade some packages on windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

When I do

```
conda update --all
```

it doesn't offer to upgrade anything.

But if I do (for example)

```
conda update pandas
```

I get

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

    numpy:  1.9.3-py27_0      --> 1.10.1-py27_0
    pandas: 0.16.2-np19py27_0 --> 0.17.0-np110py27_0
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conda automatically check for the dependencies when you update.

Pandas can work with NumPy 1.10.1, but probably you have other packages which still request NumPy 1.9.3.

If you will update NumPy and then try to update all other packages, it will probably ask you to downgrade NumPy back to 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

From here: [why does conda update downgrade some libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31501035)

> It's a compatibility issue. Anaconda is a stable
>   set of packages. When you update Anaconda, you update to this stable
>   list.
>
> However, when you update individual packages, they might cause
>   incompatibility issues with the rest of the Anaconda distribution so
>   they aren't considered stable. That's why when you use conda update
>   --all, it gets you to the latest stable Anaconda distribution, which might or might not have the version of the individual package you
>   wanted.
>
> See here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/39
>
> Edit: This behavior has changed. It now tries to increase the version
>   of all packages (except Python between major/minor version) such that
>   no packages will be incompatible with each other.
>
> See here:
>   http://continuum.io/blog/advanced-conda-part-1#conda-update-all

[-Ringil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882032/ringil)