# How do I find out what package is causing conda to want to downgrade Python?

Tags: python, conda, python-3.7

I have created a fresh conda environment based on Python 3.7.  When I try to install a bunch of packages, conda proposes to install those along with their dependencies.  Unfortunately, it also wants to downgrade Python 3.7.0 to Python 3.6.6, which defeats the purpose of the new environment.  Short of trying packages one by one, how can I check what the "offending" package triggering the downgrade is?

Related: *[why does conda update downgrade some libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31498447/974555)*