# Updating conda leads to downgrade and superseded packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Each time I want to do a `conda update conda` the following happens:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  cryptography                         2.4.2-py27hc64555f_0 --> 2.6.1-py27hcfb25f9_0
  openssl                                 1.0.2r-h0c8e037_0 --> 1.1.1b-h0c8e037_1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  jpeg                        pkgs/main::jpeg-9b-ha175dff_2 --> pkgs/free::jpeg-8d-vc9_2
  libtiff              pkgs/main::libtiff-4.0.10-h1c3b264_2 --> pkgs/free::libtiff-4.0.6-vc9_2
  pyqt                 pkgs/main::pyqt-5.6.0-py27h6e61f57_6 --> pkgs/free::pyqt-4.10.4-py27_1
  qt                     pkgs/main::qt-5.6.2-vc9hc26998b_12 --> pkgs/free::qt-4.8.7-vc9_6

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  spyder                                       3.3.4-py27_0 --> 3.2.8-py27_0
```

As soon as I am done with the update, I can run a `conda update --all`, which again updates the versions that have been superseded and therefore downgraded. Can I somehow circumvent that problem and directly do a `conda update conda`, leaving me with the updated versions without having to run a `conda update --all` afterwards?

**EDIT:**

Output of `conda config --show default_channels`:

```
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2
```

Output of `conda config --show custom_multichannels`:

```
custom_multichannels:
  local:
  defaults:
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2
```

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show channels`?

Comment: Hi @darthbith. I have the same issue. In my case, the config channels are `- defaults`. what does it mean?

Comment: @darthbith it's exactly the same for me. `- defaults`

Comment: I found a statement (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5732#issuecomment-368212423), that hints in a direction: Probably when I do `conda update conda` all packages are pinned to the `defaults` channel, whereas in `conda update --all` they are not.

Comment: @darthbith any further insight?

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show default_channels` and `conda config --show custom_multichannels`?

Comment: @darthbith edited OP to contain the requested information

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does conda update downgrade some libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498447/why-does-conda-update-downgrade-some-libraries)

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the question. Still `conda update conda` should not lead to a state where `conda update --all` does anything.